# In python, how to connect me to my private SharePoint site?

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to automate the download of all the files from one of my private SharePoint site, which is linked to my pro Teams' group. The same error occured each time I try to fix my script, and I think (but I'm not sure) it's because of an authentification problem.
Concretely, I want to download all the files from my Teams group through SharePoint. May be, it's even not possible that's why I require your help!

For my script, I took an exemple from GitHub: https://github.com/dexterai-lab/pysharepoint/blob/master/pysharepoint/interface.py. In my version, it looks like this :

```
import os
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum.site import Version


class SPInterface:
    """This is a class to interact with Sharepoint from Python"""

    def __init__(self, sharepoint_base_url, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.sharepoint_base_url = sharepoint_base_url
        self.authcookie = Office365(
            sharepoint_base_url, username=username, password=password
        ).GetCookies()

    def download_file_sharepoint(
        self, source_path, sink_path, filename, sharepoint_site
    ):
        site = Site(sharepoint_site, version=Version.v2016, authcookie=self.authcookie)
        full_source_path = os.path.join(source_path, filename)
        full_sink_path = os.path.join(sink_path, filename)
        print(full_source_path)
        print(full_sink_path)
        folder = site.Folder(source_path)
        for attempt in range(0, 3):
            try:
                output_file = open(full_sink_path, "wb")
                input_file = folder.get_file(filename)
                binary_format = bytearray(input_file)
                output_file.write(binary_format)
                output_file.close()
                print("Attempt #No: ", attempt)
                print(
                    "Downloaded file size is ",
                    round(os.path.getsize(full_sink_path) / 1024, 2),
                    " KB",
                )
            except Exception as e:
                if attempt < 2:
                    print("Try again!")
                    continue
                print("Error", e)
                raise e
            break


def main():
    # stars anonymize private datas
    sharepoint_base_url = r'https://*.sharepoint.com/'
    username = "*"
    password = "*"
    source_path = 'sites/*/Shared%20Documents/'
    sharepoint_site = r'https://*.sharepoint.com/sites/*/'
    sink_path = r'C:/Users/*'
    sp = SPInterface(sharepoint_base_url, username, password)
    sp.download_file_sharepoint(source_path, sink_path, sharepoint_site)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```